# Display shell directory in xterm title bar

Tags: bash, prompt, window-title

I created a custom prompt generated from http://bashrcgenerator.com/

`export PS1="\[$(tput bold)\]\[\033[38;5;14m\]\u\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;13m\]@\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;14m\]\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[$(t    put sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\] \[$(tput bold)\]\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;13m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\] \[$(tpu    t sgr0)\]"`

and pasted that line to the bottom of my `~/.bashrc` which did work. However, now my window only shows xterm as the title instead of the directory like it showed before.

Here is a picture to better illustrate what I mean.

[custom prompt showing xterm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyPBl.png)

[normal prompt showing directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foww2.png)

How can I still show the directory for the window title while retaining the custom prompt?

Comment: It's only showing "xterm" because nothing in your prompt sets the title.  You will have to *combine* your custom prompt with the original script (which uses a bash prompt command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `~/.bashrc`, I have:

```
# from the "xttitle(1)" man page - put info in window title
update_title()
{
    [[ $TERM = xterm ]] || [[ $TERM = xterm-color ]]  && xttitle "[$$] ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:$PWD"
}

cd()
{
    [[ -z "$*" ]] && builtin cd $HOME
    [[ -n "$*" ]] && builtin cd "$*"
    update_title
}
```

which works for me. I need to change it only when I `cd`, not at each and every command prompt.

Comment: Adding that to the end of my  `~/.bashrc` didn't resolve the title issue. Is there anything else I would need to do?

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't have xttitle installed. It works now just a little more verbose than I prefer the title to be so I'll have to tweak it. Thanks!